# Change MySQL RDS storage type from magnetic to SSD/Provisioned IOPS using Cloud Formation

Tags: mysql, architecture, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, devops

I have an RDS instance with following specs:

```
InstanceClass: db.m5.12xlarge
AllocatedStorage: 500 - (GiB)
MultiAZ: No
ReadReplica: True - (with same specs)
StorageType: standard - (magnetic)
```

I need to modify the master and the replica both to use the SSD storage type (gp2) with more space (2 TiB) AND this has to be done via CloudFormation templates as the RDS instances mentioned above are part of a stack. BUT the issue is that these are production databases and a long outage [more than 2 hours] is not an option.

The storage size change alone is okay but the type change from magnetic to SSD is something of a grey area. There is no way (at least I know of) that I can be sure that it will be done in 2+ hours or how much time will be needed. 
I want to ask the community about the best practice here or if anyone has done this before with any work arounds (manual may be) that wouldn't make the DBs out of sync of cloudformation stack as well (like making a new replica manually with desired specs and promoting it to master for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation I assume that you have a RDS - MySQL DB Cluster (if you don't have an RDS Cluster how are you replicating data to the read replica?) and not an Aurora-MySQL DB cluster (In which case you wouldn't have Magnetic storage type and hence my assumption)

In such a scenario, manually create read replicas from the UI, basically go to

> RDS -> Databases -> Select the RDS cluster -> (Top right) Choose
>   Actions -> Add Reader

Once you select the reader, choose the desired storage type and the read replica to replicate from.

This would obviously take time, but once your new replica is upto speed with the master instance, spawn another read replica (this time use the new replica you created)

Once you have 2 replicas with desired storage type, you can do 2 things:

1. If you just want read to be fast, leave the setup as it is, the initial replication of the read replica from the master would be a bit slow but read queries otherwise should be fast.
2. Otherwise, kill the master instance and RDS should automatically select the a read replica to be the new master.

For such a production system, I can't think of a more elegant way and I hope things work for you.

Comment: Yeah, thought of this manual workaround already but the change had to be triggered via CF. The downtime is there but the DB stays available during the change, although slow. But did it anyway. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, I calculated the least time was in restoring from a snapshot and creating an entirely new DB. Estimated downtime in this case is ~4 at max.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can create read replicas from cloudformation as well, just add more read replicas within your cloud formation template and specify the storage type. Once the replicas are there remove the other instances from cloudformation template. 
I haven't tried this but maybe removing the master instance directly from cloudformation may not work.  

But glad that it worked and yeah snapshots are good, but bigger the snapshots larger is the downtime.